# Trying to get property of non-object with Minecraft API

Tags: php, json

I am working with the Minecraft API and am attempting to decode JSON, and set a key as variable so that I can call it at another point. Here's my code that produces the error:

```
//grabbing the users information
if ($content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username))) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    $content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username) . '?at=0');
    $json = json_decode($content);

    foreach ($json as $currentName) {
        $input = $currentName->name;
    }

    $userSkin = "<img src='https://mcapi.ca/skin/3d/$currentName' />";
}
```

and here's the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in ... on line 31

Full PHP Code:

```
<?php

// Load the username from somewhere
if (
$username = $_POST["username"]
) {
    //do nothing 
} else {
    $username = "notch";
}


//allow the user to change the skin
$skinChange = "<a href='https://minecraft.net/profile/skin/remote?url=http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/$username.png' target='_blank' </a>";

//url to users 3D head (avatar)
$usersAvatar = "https://mcapi.ca/avatar/2d/$username/55";

//user's Avatar as favivon
$usersFavicon = "<link rel='shortcut icon' href='$usersAvatar' type='image/png' />";

//grabbing the users information
if ($content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username))
) {
  //do nothing
} else {
  $content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username) . '?at=0');
   $json = json_decode($content);

   foreach ($json as $currentName) {
    $input = $json['name'];
   }

   $userSkin = "<img src='https://mcapi.ca/skin/3d/$currentName' />";
}


// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);

// Check for error
if (!empty($json->error)) {
    die('An error happened: ' . $json->errorMessage);
}

// Save the uuid
$uuid = $json->id;

// Get the history (using $json->uuid)
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/' . urlencode($uuid) . '/names');

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);

$names = array(); // Create a new array

foreach ($json as $name) {
    $input = $name->name;

    if (!empty($name->changedToAt)) {
        // Convert to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $name->changedToAt);

        $input .= ' (changed at ' . $time . ')';
    }

    $names[] = $input; // Add each "name" value to our array "names"

}

//use $uuid tp grab UUID of the user - ---- - - - use $names to get name history of the user.



?>
```

Using `var_dump($currentName);` produces this output `string(8) "_scrunch"`

Comment: I am assuming line 31 is "$input = $currentName->name;" ? And if you can't see the error I would advise doing a couple php tutorials. This -> operator is used to access object properties. So to access array properties you do it array['key] = value. So $input = $json['name']; Look here how to access arrays with key value using forloops http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Which line is line 31?

Comment: what does `var_dump($json)` look like?

Comment: So the problem is that, you don't understand the error message? You are trying to get a property of something, that is not an object. Hmmm. Can you see, where you are referring to an object? Maybe on line 31. You may want to know what is the type or value of our variable on line 31. Let's see. Maybe use `print_r` or `var_dump` to start debugging.

Comment: But seriously, the error is at `$currentName->name` check the value of `$currentName` or `$json` to find out some more.

Comment: @floor changing to that piece of code caused an error. `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: `var_dump($currentName)` to see what you're trying to work with.

Comment: It could be that you're getting a `204 no content` response, thus `json_decode()` is failing. For example: https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/harrydenley

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK I didn't give you a piece of code to work. I implied how it would look as an array. I gave you a link to the php manual page where there are examples that do exactly what you want.

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK in the manual pages it says when you are using a key value  for loop you simply just do $input = name; Note that after the loop finishes $input will only be holding the last value of the iteration.

Comment: @deceze Although it could be marked as a duplicate, its not. OP may be getting a 204 as per the documentation "If there is no player with the given username an HTTP status code 204 (No Content) is sent without any HTTP body." http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Then `json_decode` should fail and it shouldn't even enter the loop. The exact error is still a duplicate. OP needs to at least debug why their object is not an object (as pointed to in many many dupes) and update the question accordingly. As it stands there could be any number of reasons.

Comment: @JLWillliamsUK So `$currentName` is "_scrunch", great. That's your string already. No need to do `->name` or anything at all. Just use `$currentName`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Just edit the typo instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue #1 - No user found

As per [the documentation](http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API);

> If there is no player with the given username an HTTP status code 204 (No Content) is sent **without any HTTP body**.

This means you'll be doing `json_decode();` invalid json string - which will result in `$json` not being an object, hence your error.

You should change your code to become

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' . urlencode($username) . '?at=0');
if( $http_response_header['0'] == "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content") {
    echo "no user";
    die;
}
$json = json_decode($content);
```

#### Issue #2 - Your foreach

As you're looping around the single dimensional object, `$currentName` becomes the value (a string) and not an object. Either do;

```
foreach ($json as $currentName) {
   echo $currentName . PHP_EOL; //Echo id, then echo name
}
```

Or access the properties directly

```
echo 'Id: '. $json->id;
echo '<br />';
echo 'Name: '. $json->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using `var_dump($currentName);` produces this output `string(8) "_scrunch"`

So, just as the error message says, `$currentName` is not an object. It's a string. It's the string you're looking for. You don't need to do `->name` on it, you can just use it as is.